# ffmpeg stream input sdp shows warning keyframe missing

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg 4.3.2.
I'm trying to forward a stream to a rtmp server having sdp file as input

Opening the sdp file with VLC everything is working great. The same thing happens when I use ffplay

```
ffplay -i rtp-forwarder.sdp -protocol_whitelist file,udp,rtp
```

The problem starts when I start streaming to a rtmp server. The audio is good but the video is just a black screen. I event tried to stream to youtube rtmp server but it didn't work.

I'm new to ffmpeg. Let me know if I'm missing something.

I'm using this command

```
ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist file,crypto,udp,rtp -re -i rtp-forwarder.sdp -c:v libx264 -b:v 3000k -maxrate 3000k -bufsize 6000k -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 50 -c:a aac -b:a 160k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/test
```

The sdp file content is like this

```
v=0
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 192.168.1.49
s=Pion WebRTC
c=IN IP4 192.168.1.49
t=0 0
m=audio 4000 RTP/AVP 111
a=rtpmap:111 OPUS/48000/2
m=video 4002 RTP/AVP 96
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
```

Here is a full log

```
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
[sdp @ 0000015a81ede6c0] Keyframe missing
Input #0, sdp, from 'rtp-forwarder.sdp':
  Metadata:
    title           : Pion WebRTC
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Stream #0:1: Video: vp8, yuv420p(tv, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x480, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (vp8 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (opus (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0000015a81f9e880] MB rate (108000000) > level limit (16711680) -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A
[libx264 @ 0000015a81f9e880] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0000015a81f9e880] profile High, level 6.2, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0000015a81f9e880] 264 - core 161 r3048 b86ae3c - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2021 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=50 keyint_min=5 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=cbr mbtree=1 bitrate=3000 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 vbv_maxrate=3000 vbv_bufsize=6000 nal_hrd=none filler=0 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://localhost/live/test':
  Metadata:
    title           : Pion WebRTC
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv420p, 640x480, q=-1--1, 3000 kb/s, 90k fps, 1k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 3000000/0/3000000 buffer size: 6000000 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([10][0][0][0] / 0x000A), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 160 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 aac
[flv @ 0000015a820dd200] Failed to update header with correct duration..1kbits/s speed=   1x
[flv @ 0000015a820dd200] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
frame=   13 fps=0.1 q=-1.0 Lsize=    4233kB time=00:03:07.12 bitrate= 185.3kbits/s speed=0.999x
video:440kB audio:3658kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 3.281771%
[libx264 @ 0000015a81f9e880] frame I:1     Avg QP: 1.61  size: 59263
[libx264 @ 0000015a81f9e880] frame P:3     Avg QP: 9.10  size: 44500
[libx264 @ 0000015a81f9e880] frame B:9     Avg QP: 9.80  size: 28605
[libx264 @ 0000015a81f9e880] consecutive B-frames:  7.7%  0.0%  0.0% 92.3%
[libx264 @ 0000015a81f9e880] mb I  I16..4: 36.5% 19.5% 44.0%
[libx264 @ 0000015a81f9e880] mb P  I16..4: 10.7% 50.3% 12.3%  P16..4: 11.6%  9.6%  5.5%  0.0%  0.0%    skip: 0.1%
[libx264 @ 0000015a81f9e880] mb B  I16..4:  2.2% 10.4%  3.6%  B16..8: 45.7% 21.2%  6.1%  direct:10.6%  skip: 0.1%  L0:60.0% L1:25.5% BI:14.5%
[libx264 @ 0000015a81f9e880] final ratefactor: 13.03
[libx264 @ 0000015a81f9e880] 8x8 transform intra:56.7% inter:41.9%
[libx264 @ 0000015a81f9e880] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 90.9% 99.6% 98.9% inter: 66.1% 99.0% 93.2%
[libx264 @ 0000015a81f9e880] i16 v,h,dc,p: 23% 22% 18% 38%
[libx264 @ 0000015a81f9e880] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 31% 26% 23%  4%  2%  3%  3%  4%  4%
[libx264 @ 0000015a81f9e880] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 36% 34% 18%  2%  2%  2%  2%  2%  2%
[libx264 @ 0000015a81f9e880] i8c dc,h,v,p: 55% 29% 11%  5%
[libx264 @ 0000015a81f9e880] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0000015a81f9e880] ref P L0: 59.2%  5.0% 13.4% 22.4%
[libx264 @ 0000015a81f9e880] ref B L0: 87.1%  7.5%  5.4%
[libx264 @ 0000015a81f9e880] ref B L1: 95.1%  4.9%
[libx264 @ 0000015a81f9e880] kb/s:4028.74
[aac @ 0000015a81f9a880] Qavg: 7535.380
```

I get this warning `[sdp @ 0000015a81ede6c0] Keyframe missing`
and this one after a stop it

```
[flv @ 0000015a820dd200] Failed to update header with correct duration..1kbits/s speed=   1x
[flv @ 0000015a820dd200] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the unmodified `rtp-forwarder` example in Pion? If you copied/modified it make sure you are still requesting a keyframe.

Also debugging wise can you try doing `-f out.flv` and see what that contains? If possible I would share that (and your code) and I think I could figure it out.

Comment: Yes. I'm using the rtp-forwarder example from Pion. I"ll try to generate a flv file and share it. From what I remembered I generated an mp4 file and everything worked great. Only when you forward it to rtmp server things didn't worked as planed.

Comment: Awesome! Yes please share and will do my best to help debug. Also feel free to reach out on https://pion.ly/slack we can post the working answer here afterwards for people in the future.